# C++ code for codility FrogRiverOne fails at large permutation test

Tags: c++, algorithm

Below is the link to the mentioned exercise.

https://codility.com/demo/results/demoH5GMV3-PV8

Just in case here is the task description:

A small frog wants to get to the other side of a river. The frog is currently located at position 0, and wants to get to position X. Leaves fall from a tree onto the surface of the river.

You are given a non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers representing the falling leaves. A[K] represents the position where one leaf falls at time K, measured in minutes.

The goal is to find the earliest time when the frog can jump to the other side of the river. The frog can cross only when leaves appear at every position across the river from 1 to X.

For example, you are given integer X = 5 and array A such that:

```
A[0] = 1
A[1] = 3
A[2] = 1
A[3] = 4
A[4] = 2
A[5] = 3
A[6] = 5
A[7] = 4
```

In minute 6, a leaf falls into position 5. This is the earliest time when leaves appear in every position across the river.

Write a function:

class Solution { public int solution(int X, int[] A); } 
that, given a non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers and integer X, returns the earliest time when the frog can jump to the other side of the river.

If the frog is never able to jump to the other side of the river, the function should return −1.

I don't understand how the code gives accepted answers except only one test case-the large permutation test.
I got -1 instead of 90999.

```
int solution(int X, vector<int> &A) {
// write your code in C++11
int N = A.size();
long long target = (X + 1) * X / 2;
vector<int> mark;
mark.resize(X + 1, 0);
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
    if(mark[A[i]] == 0){
        target -= A[i];
        mark[A[i]] = 1;
    }
    if(target == 0)
        return i;
}
return -1;
}
```

And when I modify the code like:

```
int solution(int X, vector<int> &A) {
// write your code in C++11
int N = A.size();
int target = X;
vector<int> mark;
mark.resize(X + 1, 0);
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
    if(mark[A[i]] == 0){
        --target;
        mark[A[i]] = 1;
    }
    if(target == 0)
        return i;
}
return -1;
}
```

it made that test case right.
Can anybody explain why?

Comment: I think this is one of the TLDR questions. Can you reduce it to something that's easier to digest? Folks trying to help don't want to go offsite to read an essay on how a puzzle is supposed to work.

Comment: OK. Here is the simple description: Given a vector A and a target number X, find the minimal index k of A to make sure A[0], A[1], ..., A[k] contains all the number from 1 to X.

Comment: Ben Voigt's answer tells you *what* is wrong, but not *why*. The reason why you got this wrong was being **too clever**. The second solution, in contrast, follows [the KISS principle: *Keep It Simple, Stupid*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Answer (score 3):

This line makes absolutely no sense:

```
long long target = (X + 1) * X / 2;
```

You're doing all the math in type `int`, there's no reason to store the result in a `long long` variable.  Any overflow has already occurred.

Of course, you already knew the problem was there, since there were only two lines of code you changed.

Comment: @Alf: Well, it's X squared that needs to overflow to cause problems, not the result squared.

Answer (score 2):

C++, score 100. Make a map then check that your map's size is equal with `X` :D

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int solution(int X, vector<int> &A) {
    map<int, bool> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
        int element = A[i];
        m[element] = true;
        if (m.size() == X) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My 100% JavaScript solution with O(N) time complexity:

```
function solution(X, A) {

    const positions = new Set();

    for (let i = 0, len = A.length; i < len; i++) {
        positions.add(A[i]);
        if (positions.size === X) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is in Java. It makes use of the fact that 1+2+..+n=n*(n+1)/2.

```
public static int solution(int X, int[] A){
    int[] Y=new int[X];  // 0 if leaf dropped here before, else 1
    int sum=X*(X+1)/2; 
    for (int i=0;(i<A.length);i++){
        if (Y[A[i]-1]==0) { //the first time a leaf drops to this position
            Y[A[i]-1]=1;
            sum-=A[i]; 
            if (sum==0) return i;            
        }     
    }
    return -1;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is in Cpp using vectors and with time complexity O(N)

```
int solution(int X, vector<int> &A) {
    int length = -1;
    std::vector<int>::iterator it;
    int max = X; int i = 0;

    std::vector<bool> visited;
    visited.reserve(X+1);
    visited.resize(X+1);

    for (it=A.begin();it!=A.end();it++, i++) {
        if(*it <= X) {
            if(!visited.at(*it)) {
                visited.at(*it) = true;
                max--;
            }
            if(max == 0) {
                length = it - A.begin();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return length;
}
```